# Self Sizing Cells and Dynamic Type in iOS 8 Doesn't resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have a problem with iOS 8 Self Sizing Cells.
I am trying to create Self Sizing cells by using this [AppCoda Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/).

According to this tutorial I have initialised my table view:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:[Cell1 description] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:Cell1Identifier];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:[Cell2 description] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:Cell2Identifier];

self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

In each cells implementation file I have initialised a property:

```
self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Also, for each cell, I have added Auto Layout constraints:

[image], [image], [image]

For the reason I don't know, cells height aren't changing dynamically.

[image]

Does anyone know why is that so?

Comment: I cannot see it clearly in the picture if you already have it, but you need a constraint between the bottom of your UILabel and the bottom of the superview so that the UILabel may "push" the superview.

Comment: There is a constraint "Bottom space to container" with 0 space

Comment: Then that shouldn't be the problem. What is the text in the label? One word only or multiple words? If it's only one word then your issue might be that `lineBreakMode` is set to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`. Setting it to `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`or add another word just for testing might help. It's set to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` by default (which you actually can see in the picture).

Comment: No, there are numerous words. My `UILabel` is high enough to display 2 lines of text, so it wraps text and divides it into 2 lines of text, but the height of cell is still static...

Comment: Are you setting this: "self.label.numberOfLines = 0;" inside "awakefromNib" method?

Comment: Yes. And because of this there is 2 lines displayed instead of 1.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are not set the "heightForRowAtIndexPath" table view delegate method in the view controller right?

Comment: I was! Wuala! It works! Please, post your answer for people like me!

Comment: Good to know that. Will post this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting up self sizing table view cells, one should not use the "heightForRowAtIndexPath" table view delegate method in the view controller.